# How to read find length of packets in bytes

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, packet

How do I find the length of a packet using DataInputStream and its readUnsignedShort/readUnsignedByte methods.

The header of the packet is 7 bytes and is as follows:

TT TT SS SS SS VV

Where:
TT is Type
SS is Size
VV is Version

I need to find the size of the packet and then print the HexBinary of it up to the given bytes that was found in the header.

I need to use he DataInputStream functions to this but how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If those are bytes:

- read the type field with `readUnsignedShort()`
- read the 3-byte length field and version field together with `readInt()`, and split them apart with a shift and a mask respectively.

Comment: How would I read them and then shift them? Is there a quicker way just to get the size?

Comment: With a shift and a mask respectively. Shift right 8 to get the length; mask with 0xff to get the version. What's the problem? And why do you think you need a quicker way?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what that means or how to do it :S Do you have an example or something? Would I just do something like: `stuff = socket.readUnsignedInt()`?

Comment: What part of 'shift right' or 'mask' don't you understand? This is extremely basic.

Comment: All of it.. I can probably google on how to do that but how do I get the stuff in the first place?

Comment: `DataInputStream` does not have a `readUnsignedInt()` method.

Comment: @Shiv If you don't know how to shift and mask in Java you need to revisit your Java 101 class. These are operators in the language. And I have *told* you *exactly* 'how to get the stuff in the first place'.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on bit shifting:

[Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

For example, assuming what you showed is expressed in bytes:

```
int type = stream.readUnsignedShort();

int size = stream.readUnsignedShort();
size <<= 8;
size |= stream.readUnsignedByte();

int version = stream.readUnsignedByte();
```

Alternatively:

```
int type = stream.readUnsignedShort();

int size = stream.readUnsignedByte();
size <<= 8;
size |= stream.readUnsignedByte();
size <<= 8;
size |= stream.readUnsignedByte();


int version = stream.readUnsignedByte();
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll test it when I get back home.

Comment: I don't think it works as I get something that is very very big... 1283112 Did you maybe miss out the masking 0xff?

Comment: No. It is more likely to be an **endian** issue instead.  Try swapping the order of the bytes in the final integer. What I find odd is that the data is using a 3-byte number to begin with (assuming the number is encoded as bytes - you still have not commented on that).

Comment: Yes, it is as bytes. Got the type and size working. Version shows 0 though: http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img673/7982/uttAOU.png You can ignore the fact that full data and size is 0. That's working now but version is still 0.